# check if specific row exist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was trying to create row dynamically on table. When a name found on autocomplete it will create row with the existing table. But my problem is i don't want to add same product in row. here `<tr></tr>` id is unique. How to avoid adding same product in the table?

```
<table class="table m-table ">
   <thead>
     <tr> 
       <th></th>                   
       <th>Product Name</th>
       <th>Unit Price</th>
       <th>Quantity</th>                   
       <th>Total </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

```js
 $('#productSearch').autocomplete({
    source: '{!! asset('productSearch') !!}',
    select:function(suggestion, ui) {
      {
        var markup = "<tr id="+ui.item.id+"><td><i class='flaticon-delete-1 delete-row' onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td><td>"+ui.item.value+"</td><td>"+ui.item.unit_price+"</td><td><input type='text' class='quantity' value='1'></td><td class='total'>"+ui.item.unit_price+"</td></tr>"; 
        $("table tbody").append(markup);           
      }           
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can check if an element with that `id` already exists in the DOM by selecting it and checking the `length` property of the resulting jQuery object, like this:

```js
$('#productSearch').autocomplete({
  source: '{!! asset('productSearch') !!}',
  select: function(suggestion, ui) {
    if ($('#' + ui.item.id).length !== 0) 
      return;

    var markup = '<tr id="' + ui.item.id + '"><td><i class="flaticon-delete-1 delete-row" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></i></td><td>' + ui.item.value + '</td><td>' + ui.item.unit_price + '</td><td><input type="text" class="quantity" value="1"></td><td class="total">' + ui.item.unit_price + '</td></tr>';
    $('table tbody').append(markup);
  }
});
```

Comment: Then it sounds like the `$('#' + ui.item.id).length` is equal to 0

Comment: Its hard to diagnose the issue without seeing your code, or any errors it generates. I'd suggest starting a new question.

Comment: Well then where have you put this line: `$(this).val("").focus();`?

Comment: Stupid question here, but have you wrapped the logic of the if in `{}`? They are omitted here as there's only one following statement. If you add more, they need to be wrapped in braces.

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla javascript

```
console.log(document.getElementById('' + ui.item.id) === null);
```